# Showing a YouTube Movie in MPMoviePlayerViewController - iPhone

Tags: iphone, youtube, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am using the following code to try and show a YouTube movie in my app. The Video player appears, shows the controls for a second, and then the movie player retracts. The app does not crash. Any ideas how to make this work?

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController *mpViewController = 
[[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] 
initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VKsVSBhSwJg"]];

[mpViewController shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight animated:NO];

[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:mpViewController];

[mpViewController release];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't remember where I read it, but I do remember that YouTube doesn't let you play videos in an `MPMoviePlayerViewController` -- you have to point the user to the YouTube app or use a `UIWebView` (as they detail [here](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2009/02/youtube-apis-iphone-cool-mobile-apps.html)). I suppose you *could* do what Felz suggests but it would be against YouTube's policies.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ah, I had read that but it was dated 2009 so I thought it might have been upgraded by now.

Comment: Oh yes! Certainly against policy. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

The URL you point the player to must be a supported file format (e.g. H.264 encoded mp4). Youtube urls are HTML with an embedded player that loads the actual movie. Getting a playable mp4 in youtube is possible, but not that simple (this may have changed, last time I did this was about a year ago). Youtube videos have a few guards against hotlinking that make getting the actual H.264 URL tricky.

For testing the player, try setting up a web server with one of the [sample files](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1425) apple provides.

As for getting youtube videos, it is possible, it is tricky (some screen-scraping needed), it is a bit of a moving target.